# Square inscribed in an isosceles right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area

3 different shapes are inscribed in an isosceles right triangle. Given that the side shorter side of the isosceles right triangle to be 2. Find their areas.

I have found the area of the 1st and 2nd diagram but could not find the area of the 3rd figure. Appreciate any help. [image]

Comment: If $S$ is the area of the yellow square, then the area of triangle $ABC$ is $S+S/2+S/2+S/4$. It follows that $S=8/9$. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: how do you know that the smallest right triangle is S/4?

Comment: Four small triangles with vertex $B$ form a square equal to yellow.

Answer (score 4):

Reflect the triangle across its legs $AB$ and $BC$.  Because $AB = BC = 2$, the resulting figure is a square.  Moreover, since the inscribed yellow shape is also a square, it is easy to see that their reflections must form a central square that is congruent, and in fact, the entire figure consists of $9$ congruent squares.  From this, it is trivial to compute the desired area.  See the figure below.

[image]

---

If we label your figure as follows:

[image]

then show that we must have $EF = FC$, and similarly, $AG = GD$.  Hence conclude that $GF = AC/3$ and the rest is obvious.

Comment: Thank you. If I were to solve algebraically, how would I find the area of the yellow square in figure 3?

Comment: @Joe Please clarify.  Do you want the calculation based on the reasoning provided in my illustration, or do you want a solution based on your figure with a more traditional algebraic approach?

Comment: Hi, can you show me a more traditional algebraic approach also? Thanks